# Merging Dataframes with Pandas on LEFT or RIGHT

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

```
entity_data = {'STATE_CD_E': ['NY', 'NY', 'NY'],
           'INTERMEDIATE_NUMBER_E': ['1111', '2222', '3333'],
           'DISTRICT_NUMBER_E': ['123456789012', '123412341234', 
           '121212121212'],
           'FINANCE_NUMBER_E': ['123456', '123412', '121212']  }

df_entity = pd.DataFrame(entity_data, index = ['School_1', 'School_2', 
            'School_3'])

finance_data = {'STATE_CD_F': ['NY', 'NY', 'NY'],
           'INTERMEDIATE_NUMBER_F': ['1111', '2222', '3333'],
           'DISTRICT_NUMBER_F': ['123456', '123412', '121212']  }

df_finance = pd.DataFrame(finance_data, index = ['School_1', 'School_2', 
             'School_3'])

print("\n")
print(df_entity)
print("\n")
print(df_finance)
print("\n")
print("\n")
print("\n")



df_merge = pd.merge(df_entity, df_finance[['INTERMEDIATE_NUMBER_F', 
           'DISTRICT_NUMBER_F']], right_on = ['DISTRICT_NUMBER_F'], left_on= 
           ['FINANCE_NUMBER_E'], how='left')
```

Above is the code I am using. I'm trying to merge two dataframes using pandas. However, I want to join on the left 6 digits of DISTRICT_NUMBER_E with DISTRICT_NUMBER_F. Is there anyway to do this? If not, can I create a new column in the entity_data dataframe that takes the left 6 digits of DISTRICT_NUMBER_E and then match on that column instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just merge on the first six digits as such:

```
df_entity.merge(df_finance, left_on=df_entity.DISTRICT_NUMBER_E.str[:6],
                right_on='DISTRICT_NUMBER_F')

  DISTRICT_NUMBER_E FINANCE_NUMBER_E INTERMEDIATE_NUMBER_E STATE_CD_E  \
0      123456789012           123456                  1111         NY   
1      123412341234           123412                  2222         NY   
2      121212121212           121212                  3333         NY   

  DISTRICT_NUMBER_F INTERMEDIATE_NUMBER_F STATE_CD_F  
0            123456                  1111         NY  
1            123412                  2222         NY  
2            121212                  3333         NY
```

Comment: that doesn't pull in DISTRICT_NUMBER_F when I run the code that you gave me.

Comment: @Taylor, what does this code not do? What do you want that this code does not do?

Comment: No, you're right. I was printing the original df_entity. I set it to a new variable and then printed it out, and got your output to match. That works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
# create a key which satisfy the condition for joining the dataframes
df_entity['key'] = df_entity['DISTRICT_NUMBER_E'].str[:6]

# join the both dataframe using the new key into one merged dataframe
# optional use caluse how = 'left'/'right'/'outer' for specific join
merged_df = pd.merge(df_entity, df_finance, left_on='key', right_on='DISTRICT_NUMBER_F')

# optional: dorp the key if not needed anymore
merged_df.drop('key', axis=1, inplace=true)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @Nic3500 thanks for noticing. I have added few clarification on the code.